# Website has been renamed. How can I redirect subdomain.OldURL.com to subdomain.NewURL.com

Tags: redirect, heroku, dns, url-routing, nameservers

The old name was http://cappedin.com.

The new name is http://cappedsports.com

I set up a 301 DNS redirect cappedin.com to cappedsports.com

How can I get a subdomain.cappedin.com to be redirected to the same subdomain.cappedsports with a DNS entry?

Comment: there is no such thing as 301 DNS redirect, 301 is a HTTP response code. But anyway, you knew how to redirect the root domain, what is preventing you from doing the exactly same setup for subdomain?

Comment: Some dns providers have a pseudo record in their dns panels that does an http redirect from servers managed by the dns provider. It could be possible that's what op is referring to.

Comment: @slindsey3000 what dns provider are you using?

Comment: @captncraig I am using DNSSimple. It is a pseudo "url" record for the redirect on the root domain. I would like to redirect all traffic the root cappedin.com along with user99.cappedin.com - Both of these should be directed to the correct IP through DNS. Possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [DNSimple's docs](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/redirector/) on their URL redirects, it says:

> The redirector currently doesn’t support redirect targets that include
>   a back-reference (match) to the redirect source. For example, the
>   following redirects will not work:

```
*.foo.com to bar.com/$1
*.foo.com to $1.bar.com
```

So unfortunately, they don't seem to allow what you are trying to do. You would need to add a URL record for each subdomain you want to redirect, or redirect the wildcard to a single destination domain.

To reiterate, this is not a "DNS Redirect". It is a http redirection service provided by DNSimple. It works like this:

1. You add a URL record to your domain in DNSimple.
2. They add a [hidden to you] A record pointing that name at their own servers.
3. Their http servers issue 301 redirects to your domain.

You could cut out the middle man and make a wildcard A for the redirect domain to a server you control that can perform whatever custom 301 logic you wish.

Comment: Thank you. So *.cappedin.com can not be mapped/redirected to *.cappedsports.com? I handle the logic for the subdomain at the application level. Its fine if all *.cappedin.com gets redirected as long as the subdomain is in tact because I parse this subdomain when the request comes in.

Comment: I think you are basically saying no... ha. I'm just wishing there was some way to not only redirect the main url but also just redirect all subdomains...

Comment: You could redirect all subdomains to a single target. Like `*.domaina.com -> domainb.com`, but you can't keep the subdomain currently, no.